# jQuery Bootstrap confirmation on dynamically created button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have my code below that works on buttons that were inserted via regular HTML.  However when I add the button dynamically with jQuery, the button doesn't work.  I tried using this from a previous Stackoverflow response, but I can't get it to work.  Any help is appreciated.

The answer that I found:

```
$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

My code

```
$('.mini-admin').confirmation({
    placement: 'left',
  onConfirm: function(event, element) { 
      var c = $( element ).data('row');

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "_scripts/deleteUser.php",
            data: {c: c},
            context: document.body,
            success: function(){
                $( '#row_' + c ).fadeOut();
                console.log('1');
            }
      });
  },
  onCancel: function() { }
});
```

This code will work on the second click, I can't figure out how to make it work on the first click!

```
$('table.users-form').on('click', '.mini-admin', function() {
    $('.mini-admin').confirmation({
        placement: 'left',
      onConfirm: function(event, element) { 
          var c = $( element ).data('row');

          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "_scripts/deleteUser.php",
                data: {c: c},
                context: document.body,
                success: function(){
                    $( '#row_' + c ).fadeOut();
                    console.log('2');
                }
          });
      },
      onCancel: function() { }
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping my original code in this block made it work. (don't ask me why)

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {

});
```